# How to signal a Indy TCPServer connection thread to terminate?

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver, delphi-10.3-rio

Before I shutdown the Indy TCPServer with `Active:= False`, I must signal all connections to abort what they doing and exit, because otherwise the server will be blocked and, with it, my application too.

From what I can think of, I need two things:

1. A way to send a `Disconnect`, because the thread may be blocked reading for commands.
2. A way to signal the thread to terminate, like `Terminate;` method of the `TThread`. I searched through server and I didn't found something similar. I know sending a `Disconnect` will throw an exception and the thread will exit, but maybe the thread is not reading and is busy doing something.

I tried this, but, of course, is not working and it corrupts my application and the system close it...

```
procedure TMyTcpServer.StopServer;
var List: TIdContextList;
    I: Integer;
begin
 List:= Contexts.LockList;
 for I:= 0 to List.Count -1 do
  TIdContext(List.Items[I]).Connection.Disconnect(False);
 Contexts.UnlockList;
 Active:= False;
end;
```

Comment: The server's `Active` setter already disconnects all client sockets. You don't need to do that manually.  That disconnect should cause any I/O operations to fail with an exception raised. Make sure you are not swallowing that exception, let the server handle it so it can cleanup the socket and owning thread. But, like you said, if a thread is not in the middle of a socket I/O and is doing some other task, then you will just have to signal that task in your own way. For instance, with a global `boolean` that the task can look at periodically...

Comment: ... Or, you can access the underlying thread via the `TIdYarnOfThread(Context.Yarn).Thread` property so you can call `Terminate()` on it, but I don't recommend doing that, and it won't really solve the non-I/O issue anyway.